# How to make a function to find the difference between each element of two arrays of equal length

Tags: c, arrays

The function supposedly checks if the size of both arrays are the same. If they are, compare each index of both arrays and see which one has a greater value. Store the bigger value inside a third array. If both values are equal, then store a zero inside the 3rd array. Prior to the end of the function, display all the elements in the third array. If sizes of both arrays are not equal, then display "Comparison is not possible".

All I have tried is brute force studying ANSI C but I'm still a bit lost.

#### Example 1:

Input:

```
arrA[] = {1, 4, 7, 8, 9};
arrB[] = {3, 2, 7, 8, 6};
```

Output:

```
arrC[] = {3, 4, 0, 0, 9};
```

#### Example 2:

Input:

```
arrA[] = {1, 2, 3};                          
arrB[] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 9};
```

Output:

Comparison is not possible.

Comment: So you have `void cmparrays (int *a, int *b, size_t sza, size_t szb) { ... }` and you have passed both arrays and the size of each to your function. (you can also pass `int *c, size_t szc` as parameters if you need to pass a 3rd array in). Now just implement your logic. Where are you stuck?

Comment: ***Show your code***

Comment: (1) You must know the size of both the arrays beforehand to check whether they are equal or not. (2) Pass array 1, array 2, size 1, size 2 to the function. (3) exit if (size 1!= size 2). (4) loop from i = 0 to i = size 1 or size 2. And compare array 1[i] and array 2[i]. Put the max in a third array. After completion of loop return the start address of third array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a function called "sizeof".

```
if(sizeof(arrA) == sizeof(arrB)){
    //OK
}else{
    //NG
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: 単純に英語を間違えていましたか。修正ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your function and take it piece-by-piece, first and foremost, since your comparison can either succeed (equal sized arrays) or fail (unequal sized arrays), you should choose a return type that can indicate success or failure. Type `int` is fine, you can choose your scheme, e.g. `-1` is failure, `1` for success, or `0/1` -- just be consistent. So your function prototype (presuming you want to fill `arrC[]` in your function and make the filled `arrC[]` usable back in the caller), you could do:

```
int cmparrays (int *a, int *b, int *c, size_t sza, size_t szb, size_t szc)
{
    ...
```

You mention ANSI C, that will inject an additional caveat in that ANSI C requires are variable declarations at the beginning of each scope and does not provide for declaring loop variables within the `for` loop statement itself, so you would need:

```
    size_t i;   /* ANSI C requires variable declarations before statements */
```

The first order of business should be a comparison between the size of `arrA[]` and `arrB[]`. If they are unequal your comparison fails and you should return error. As a second part of the test, you should ensure that the size of `arrC[]` is at least as big as the size of `arrA[]` and `arrB[]`. You could do:

```
    if (sza != szb || szc < sza) {  /* validate sizes */
        fputs ("Comparison is not possible\n.", stderr);
        return -1;  /* return -1 indicating error */
    }
```

If all is good, just output your prefix for the `arrC[]` elements, e.g.

```
    fputs ("arrC[] = {", stdout);               /* output prefix */
```

(which will output `"arrC[] = {"` setting up for the rest of the elements to be output)

Now it is just a matter of looping over the elements in `arrA[]` and `arrB[]` and if they are equal assigning `0` to that element of `arrC[]`, otherwise, assign the larger to `arrC[]`. That can be done with a simple loop, an `if ... else` and a `ternary` operator, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < sza; i++) {                 /* loop over each element */
        if (a[i] == b[i])                       /* if elements equal */
            c[i] = 0;                           /* set to zero */
        else    /* otherwise */
            c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] : b[i];   /* set to larger element */
        printf (i ? ", %d" : "%d", c[i]);       /* output value */
    }
```

All that remains is outputting the *suffix* for your output and returning an indication of success:

```
    fputs ("};\n", stdout);     /* tidy up with closing brace & newline */

    return 1;   /* return success */
}
```

Putting it altogether in a short example to test both equal and unequal array lengths, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cmparrays (int *a, int *b, int *c, size_t sza, size_t szb, size_t szc)
{
    size_t i;   /* ANSI C requires variable declarations before statements */

    if (sza != szb || szc < sza) {  /* validate sizes */
        fputs ("Comparison is not possible\n.", stderr);
        return -1;  /* return -1 indicating error */
    }

    fputs ("arrC[] = {", stdout);               /* output prefix */

    for (i = 0; i < sza; i++) {                 /* loop over each element */
        if (a[i] == b[i])                       /* if elements equal */
            c[i] = 0;                           /* set to zero */
        else    /* otherwise */
            c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] : b[i];   /* set to larger element */
        printf (i ? ", %d" : "%d", c[i]);       /* output value */
    }
    fputs ("};\n", stdout);     /* tidy up with closing brace & newline */

    return 1;   /* return success */
}

int main (void) {
#ifndef TESTUNEQUAL
    int arrA[] = {1, 4, 7, 8, 9},
        arrB[] = {3, 2, 7, 8, 6},
#else
    int arrA[] = {1, 2, 3},
        arrB[] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 9},
#endif
        arrC[sizeof arrA/sizeof *arrA] = {0};
    size_t  sza = sizeof arrA/sizeof *arrA,
            szb = sizeof arrB/sizeof *arrB,
            szc = sizeof arrC/sizeof *arrC;

    if (cmparrays (arrA, arrB, arrC, sza, szb, szc) == -1)
        return 1;
    /* you can use array arrC[] here and below */
}
```

(**note:** the use of a simply preprocessor definition for `TESTUNEQUAL` to change the declarations for `arrA[]` and `arrB[]` if the `-DTESTUNEQUAL` define is passed as part of the compile string)

**Example Use/Output**

With equal length arrays:

```
$ ./bin/cmparrays
arrC[] = {3, 4, 0, 0, 9};
```

or compiling with `TESTUNEQUAL` defined:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Ofast -o bin/cmparrays_unequal \
cmparrays.c -DTESTUNEQUAL

$ ./bin/cmparrays_unequal
Comparison is not possible
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the super detailed response. I'm really trying to go through all of it and understand. We're in the middle of hell week so i might not be able to respond with a question til we're done with the exams and stuff. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to get length of array, you need to divide sizeof array you want to check with type of the array, example:

```
int arrA[] = {1, 4, 7, 8, 9};
int sizeOfArrayA = sizeof(arrA)/sizeof(int);
```

in *sizeOfArrayA*  you will get 5.

below code is example:

```
int compare(int* arrA, int sizeA, int* arrB, int sizeB, int* arrC){
    int i;
    if(sizeA != sizeB)
        return -1;

    for(i=0;i<sizeA;i++){
        if(arrA[i]==arrB[i])
            arrC[i] = 0;
        else if(arrA[i]>arrB[i])
            arrC[i] = arrA[i];
        else
            arrC[i] = arrB[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int arrA[] = {1, 4, 7, 8, 9};
    int arrB[] = {3, 2, 7, 8, 6};
    int arrC[50] = {0};

    if(compare(
            arrA, sizeof(arrA)/sizeof(int),
            arrB, sizeof(arrB)/sizeof(int),
            arrC) != 0)
    {
        printf("Comparison is not possible.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```